# Error when using apt upgrade: Errors were encounternt while processing: linux-image-6.2.0-36.generic

Tags: apt, moveit-tutorial

Hello I also have the issue of only seeing a black screen when using rviz over the docker. I wanted to try upgrading the mesa package but the upgrade didn't work.
I get the Error:
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (--configure):
installed linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encounternt while processing:
linux-image-6.2.0-36.generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

I am new to Ros programming and I did the following steps for controlling the IGUS Robot
https://github.com/CommonplaceRobotics/iRC_ROS
So I am using a VirtualMachine with Ubuntu 22.04
https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Ubuntu-Install-Debians.html

and then the tutorial on how to start with Moveit2
https://moveit.ros.org/install-moveit2/binary/
here I did both ways - when using the docker I get the Error. (when not using the docker, i can't get the robot so that isn't a solution)

Unfortunately I don't know how to fix that error and I cound't find something helpfull on the internet. Can someone help me?
Thank you very much!

```
      I also had this problem with windows 10 enterprise, docker-desktop and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. I was able to fix this issue by upgrading the mesa package with the binaries provided by the kisak/kisak-mesa ppa:

add-apt-repository ppa:kisak/kisak-mesa
apt update
apt upgrade
```

Originally posted by @Stefan-working in #948 (comment)